# Coarsest filtration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr F, \mathsf P)$ be some probaility space, $T = [0,+\infty)$ and $\eta = (\eta_t)_{t\in T}$ be some real-valued stochastic process. I say that a stochastic process $\xi$ is good if it is a Markov process with respect to its natural filtration $\mathscr F^\xi$, and $\eta_t = g(\xi_t)$ at any moment $t\in T$ for some measurable $g$.

Does there exist the "simplest" good process, that is the one which has the coarsest filtration? If it does, I think the proof would involve fixpoint theorem for monotone functions, however I am not sure how to translate the two conditions above into monotone functions on filtrations.

Comment: @TheBridge: I was not suggesting that, why would you?

Comment: I think a trivial process $\xi_t = 1$ always works in my case, since $\eta$ will be independent of it.

Comment: @TheBridge: I still don't get it, do you mean that for such process there does not exist the coarsest Markov super-pricess?

Comment: @ Ilya: Do you assume that such a $\xi$ exists and $\xi$ is adapted to $\mathcal F$?

Comment: $\mathcal F$ here is the $\sigma$-algebra on the original probability space, so yes, $\xi_t$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable for all $t$. W.r.t. existence, the shift process on $\omega$ satisfies all required properties. However, it is a very expensive process in terms of filtration.